# Getting a distinct column with laravel blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to make this query:

`SELECT DISTINCT field_1 FROM Table1`

#### My Model:

```
public function ano_semestre()
{
   return Turma::distinct()->select('ano_semestre')->get()->toArray();
}
```

#### My View:

```
@foreach($professor as $key => $prof)
      @foreach($prof->ano_semestre as $semestre)
           {{ dd($semestre->ano_semestre) }}
       @endforeach
 @endforeach
```

#### MY Controller:

```
public function getProfessorList()
{
    $professor = Professor::all();
    return View::make('professor', compact('professor'));
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

The error occurs when I try to access this:

`$prof->ano_semestre`

Answer (score 1):

In your view, you've accessed the `ano_semestre` attribute, not the method. You've used `$prof->ano_semestre`, not `$prof->ano_semestre()`.

In Laravel, when accessing a Model's attribute, it first checks to see if the attribute exists as a field. If not, then it checks to see if there is a method on the model with the same name as the attribute. If so, it assumes this method is a relationship method, and relationship methods must return a `Relation` object (as your error message has shown).

You have not defined this correctly to be a relationship method, and it doesn't look like you were trying to. Just make sure you're calling the method, and not attempting to use it as an attribute. Change `$prof->ano_semestre` to `$prof->ano_semestre()`.